# Chrome extension read GET request

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, request

Currently trying to create a chrome extension which needs to listen to the page's HTTP requests, waiting for the request for an image file (which always has a different name), and then handle the URL of this image.

I can't seem to understand how to read the page's requests from my extension so what would be the best way of handling the situation?

Comment: Is it a solution, instead of changing the url after the request is made, to change the `src` property of the `img` elements via javascript?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

Comment: Could you provide sample code for the listener? And how to get the response?